# An infinite sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{a=k}^\infty a2^{-a}\binom{a-1}{k-1}=2k$$
I have simplified this series to use the binomial theorem:
$$\sum\limits_{b=0}^\infty (b+k)2^{-b-k}\binom{b+k-1}{k-1}$$
However, $(b+k)$ does not make that possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{a=k}^{\infty}\color{blue}{a\binom{a-1}{k-1}}2^{-a}=\sum_{a=k}^{\infty}\color{blue}{k\binom{a}{k}}2^{-a}\underset{a=n+k}{=}2^{-k}k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}2^{-n}=2^{-k}k\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-k-1}=2k.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{a = k}^{\infty}a\,2^{-a}
{a - 1 \choose k - 1}} =
\sum_{a = k}^{\infty}a\,2^{-a}{a - 1 \choose a - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{a = k}^{\infty}a\,2^{-a}
{-k \choose a - k}\pars{-1}^{a - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{-k}\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\pars{a + k}\,\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}}^{a}
{-k \choose a}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left. 2^{-k}\pars{x\,\partiald{}{x} + k}
\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}{-k \choose a}x^{a}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left. 2^{-k}\pars{x\,\partiald{}{x} + k}
\pars{1 + x}^{-k}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{-k}\,\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}-kx\pars{1 + x}^{-k - 1}\ +\
k\pars{1 + x}^{-k}}_{\ x\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{2k} \\ &\
\end{align}